# So many ways to format the same data

Tags: java, formatting

Is there any difference in these four ways of formatting the same data?

```
    // Solution 1
    System.out.printf("%.1\n",10.99f);

    // Solution 2
    System.out.format("%.1\n",10.99f);

    // Solution 3
    System.out.print(String.format("%.1\n",10.99f));

    // Solution 4
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
    System.out.print(formatter.format("%.1\n",10.99f));
    formatter.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

The first two are exactly the same, since `printf` is implemented as ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.printf%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29))

```
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object ... args) {
    return format(format, args);
}
```

The latter two are also exactly the same, since `String.format` is implemented as ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.format%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29))

```
public static String format(String format, Object ... args) {
    return new Formatter().format(format, args).toString();
}
```

Finally, the 2nd and the 4th are more or less the same, as can be seen from the implementation of `PrintStream.format` ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.format%28java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)). Under the hood, it also creates a new 
`Formatter` (if needed) and calls `format` on that `Formatter`.

```
public PrintStream format(String format, Object ... args) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            if ((formatter == null)
                || (formatter.locale() != Locale.getDefault()))
                formatter = new Formatter((Appendable) this);
            formatter.format(Locale.getDefault(), format, args);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream` For detail follow this Link : [Details about various format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

An invocation of this method of the form

`out.printf(Locale l, String format,Object... args)`

behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation

`out.format(Locale l,String format,Object... args)`

So 1 & 2 are same there is not any difference b/w them.
and 3 & 4 are almost same only compilation time difference will be there if compared with 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that `String.format()` calls `new Formatter().format()` and `PrintWriter.printf()` calls almost the same there shouldn't be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.printf()`, `System.out.format()` are methods of `PrintStream`.They are equivalent.

`printf()` just displays the newly formatted String to `System.out`, while `format()` return you a new formatted string.